# Evaluate symbolic matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I defined 2 symbolic matrix in MATLAB, for example

```
w = sym('w',[10,10])
```

Then I do some operations on it and get function `E` dependent to symbolic matrix `w` and `v`. Now, I want to evaluate `E` numerically with numerical `w` and `v`.

How can I do this?

Comment: The function which you probably are looking for is [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html). Consider using anonymous functions instead of sym

Comment: @SardarUsama function E= w11*v1*some other things+...+ w_nn*v_n*some others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use such code:

```
 >> w=sym('w',[10 10]);
 >> d=sym('d',[10 1]);
 >> E=W*d + ...(some other operations)
 >> define a numerical matrix f and vector x)
 >> subs(subs(E,w,f),d,x)
```

This code performed in `R2014a` and had a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example on R2017a:

```
>> syms E(v,w)
>> E(v,w) = v*w + v;
>> E(3,4)
ans = 
    15
```

On earlier versions, I believe `symfun` is the command to use.

Comment: i can evaluate such example, but i can't evaluate a matrix